# Connection with sslv3 page with urllib2

Tags: ssl, urllib2

Hi I am working on a [classified web page](http://www.clasf.co.za)  and I need to know a secure connection with urllib2; I get an error when I try to connect to a web page that requires sslv3 connection.

Does anybody knows how to arrange this? It is possible to fix it with a new python version?

Answer (score 0):

The server at `clasf.co.za` simply does not support SSL at all (port 443 connection refused). Which means there is nothing on the client side you can do to establish a SSL connection to the server. A short test of using https to this site with a browser should give you problems too.